# How can I find all symlinks linking to a renamed volume?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, grep, symlink

I had a change a volume name and I have dozens of (now broken) symlinks (at least) throughout my system.

How can I easily find all symlinks matching my old volume name?

Let's assume my old volume was named "OldVolume" and my new one is named "NewVolume".

I assume it will be some version of:

```
find / -type l -ls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type l | (while read FN ; do test -e "$FN" || ls -ld "$FN"; done)
```

will find your broken symlinks. To limit the output, you could simple pipe the above into a grep:

```
find . -type l | (while read FN ; do test -e "$FN" || ls -ld "$FN"; done) | \
    grep OldVolume
```

Comment: Is there any way to limit to symlinks matching "OldVolume"?